# ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container: null

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

I have a React demo with [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) on here (http://jsfiddle.net/zhaozhiming/cLp7L5xe/).
Click the button to change the table column headers, but it always have warning on console:

```
ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container: null
```

What is the warning reason and how to fix it? Thanks

I know there [have a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780891/reactjs-reactmount-root-element-has-been-removed-from-its-original-container) like my question, but it seems have different reason.

Answer (score 0):

The way curretnly your using a Handsontable is formal java script way so in your case what happen it's not maintained by React when elements render on Browser so this warning popup here is an example how to use Hansonetable with JSX

[Handsone JSX](https://github.com/thrashr888/mathr/blob/master/app/scripts/components/HandsOnTable.jsx)

Comment: Thank you for reply @Dhaval Patel, but your example look like as same as my demo. It just different with the old API and new API. Is there something I missing?